# No LogCat output from AVD?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

When I start my avd and deploy my application, there is no output being send to LogCat, any thoughts of how to fix this? When it happens I just re-make the project and add all the files. Is there any way to force the logcat tab to grab output from a specific avd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

focus your app in Devices in Windows/ Show View

Comment: Could you be more specific? So, window->other->android->devices and then make sure the avd im using is highlighted?